# Select from table where column like list

Tags: kdb

I have the following table:

```
t : ([]date:.z.D - til 3; min_max: ((0w;0w);(5;8);(10;15)))
```

which looks like this:

```
date       min_max
------------------
2019.06.06 0w 0w  
2019.06.05 5  8   
2019.06.04 10 15
```

Note that `min_max` column is a list, hence its type = `"F"`.

**Question:**

How do I select rows where `min_max = (0w;0w)`, such that the resulting query would give only the first row:

```
date       min_max
------------------
2019.06.06 0w 0w
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is use the following select statement which uses match with the each-left adverb:

```
q)select from t where min_max ~\: (0w;0w)
date       min_max
------------------
2019.06.06 0w 0w
q)\ts:1000 select from t where min_max ~\: (0w;0w)
2 1904
```

Alternatively you could also use the following statement which uses the `in` keyword. The two queries are comparable in terms of speed though the second query uses more memory:

```
q)select from t where min_max in enlist (0w;0w)
date       min_max
------------------
2019.06.06 0w 0w
q)\ts:1000 select from t where min_max in enlist (0w;0w)
2 1936
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways to do this:

**Using '?' (to get the first occurrence)**

```
q) select from t where i in min_max?enlist 2#0w
```

**Using '=' (to get all occurrences)**

```
q)  select from t where all@'min_max=\:2#0w
```

Output

```
date       min_max
------------------
2019.06.06 0w 0w
```

Comment: I think `?` would only return the first occurrence

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have mentioned one solution to get first row only and one to get all. I should have mentioned that in the post. Adding that now.

Answer (score 2):

Can use match (~) to achieve this:

```
q)select from t where min_max ~\: (0w;0w)
date       min_max
------------------
2019.06.06 0w 0w
```

https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/match/